How can I calculate the development time for my GitHub project and estimate time for new tasks?
I'm looking for a way to calculate the total time spent developing my project on GitHub. Additionally, I would like to estimate the time required for future tasks based on my current workflow.
Is there a way to track the actual time spent on commits or development sessions for my existing project?
Are there any tools or workflows that can help me estimate the time needed for new tasks based on my past development pace?
Ideally, I'd like a solution that integrates with GitHub or any external tool that can analyze my GitHub activity for these insights.
Ideally, I'd like a solution that integrates with GitHub or any external tool that can analyze my GitHub activity for these insights.

Funtion Point Analysis. "History" tells you how long it took you to develop a given set of function points. "Extracting" function points from new projects allows you to estimate the effort required to implement those fuctions (based on prior history). Which then leads to language "gearing factors" as your toolset expands.
